# Perl RegExp matching only outermost expression

Tags: regex, perl

Here's a simplified example of a string I want to parse:

```
$my_string = "000 AAA 111 ZZZ AAA 222 AAA 333 ZZZ ZZZ 444"
```

I want to retrieve what's in between `AAA` & `ZZZ`, BUT I want to ignore what's in a nested `AAA`/`ZZZ`. So in the above example, I want `111` and `222` (they're numbers in this example, but they can be anything alphanumeric with the exception of `AAA` or `ZZZ`), but I'd ignore `333` because it's within a nested `AAA`/`ZZZ`. And there could be any number of nested `AAA`/`ZZZ`. Example:

```
$my_string2 = "AAA 1 AAA 2 AAA 3 AAA 4 ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ"
```

In this second example, I would want only `1`.

Comment: In the second example, how are you determining what's nested?

Comment: You should include what you tried so far and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Basically, anytime you see an `AAA` before a prior `AAA` has had a matching `ZZZ`, I consider it nested.

Comment: You can use a recursive regex like `/(AAA(?: ( (?:[^Z])++ | (?:Z(?!ZZ)(?2)) | (?:ZZ(?!Z)(?2))) | (?1) )*ZZZ)*/xg` but it would need some post processing of the returned capture groups to get your desired result..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of recursive parsing. In this case, you are only interested
in level 1 content.

***Added example segment that parses all core's or single level core's (speeds things up).*

```
 # (?s)(?:((?&content))|AAA((?&core)|)ZZZ|((?:AAA|ZZZ)))(?(DEFINE)(?<core>(?>(?&content)|AAA(?:(?=.)(?&core)|)ZZZ)+)(?<content>(?>(?!(?:AAA|ZZZ)).)+))

 # //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 # // The General Guide to 3-Part Recursive Parsing
 # // ----------------------------------------------
 # // Part 1. CONTENT
 # // Part 2. CORE
 # // Part 3. ERRORS

 (?s)

 (?:
      (                                  # (1), Take off CONTENT
           (?&content) 
      )
   |                                   # OR
      AAA                                # Start-Delimiter
      (                                  # (2), Take off The CORE
           (?&core) 
        |  
      )
      ZZZ                                # End-Delimiter

   |                                   # OR
      (                                  # (3), Take off Unbalanced (delimeter) ERRORS
           (?: AAA | ZZZ )
      )
 )

 # ///////////////////////
 # // Subroutines
 # // ---------------

 (?(DEFINE)

      # core
      (?<core>
           (?>
                (?&content) 
             |  
                AAA 
                # recurse core
                (?:
                     (?= . )
                     (?&core) 
                  |  
                )
                ZZZ
           )+
      )

      # content 
      (?<content>
           (?>
                (?!
                     (?: AAA | ZZZ )
                )
                . 
           )+
      )

 )
```

Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
my $content = <DATA>;

# Set the error mode on/off here ..
my $BailOnError = 1;
my $IsError = 0;

my @vals = ();
my $level = 0;

ParseCore( $content );

print "\n@vals";
exit;

sub ParseCore
{
    my ($core) = @_;
    while ( $core =~ /(?s)(?:((?&content))|AAA((?&core)|)ZZZ|((?:AAA|ZZZ)))(?(DEFINE)(?<core>(?>(?&content)|AAA(?:(?=.)(?&core)|)ZZZ)+)(?<content>(?>(?!(?:AAA|ZZZ)).)+))/g )
    {
       if (defined $1)
       {
         # CONTENT
           if ( $level == 1 ) {
               push @vals, $1;
           }
       }
       elsif (defined $2)
       {
         # CORE
           my $k = $2;

           # To parse all core's:
           # -----------------------
           # ++$level;
           # ParseCore( $k );
           # --$level;

           # To parse just level 1 core's:
           # ----------------------------------
           if ( $level == 0 ) {
              ++$level;
              ParseCore( $k );
              --$level;
           }

           if ( $BailOnError && $IsError ) {
               last;
           }
       }
       else
       {
         # ERRORS
           print "Unbalanced '$3' at position = ", $-[0];
           $IsError = 1;

           # Decide to continue here ..
           # If BailOnError is set, just unwind recursion. 
           # -------------------------------------------------
           if ( $BailOnError ) {
              last;
           }
       }
    }
}

#================================================
__DATA__

000 AAA 111 ZZZ AAA 222 AAA 333 ZZZ ZZZ 444
AAA 1 AAA 2 AAA 3 AAA 4 ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ
```

Output:

```
111   222     1
```